# Reduce an array of objects to the unique strings found in a property shared by all objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I've written a javascript function that successfully returns an array of all the unique classes used in a HTML document.

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

let classesUsedInHtml = htmlCollection => {
  let uniqClassSelectors = [];
  Array.from(htmlCollection)
    .filter(element => element.classList.length > 0)
    .map(element =>
      element.classList.forEach(
        item =>
          uniqClassSelectors.includes(item)
            ? null
            : uniqClassSelectors.push(item)
      )
    );
  return uniqClassSelectors;
};

console.log(classesUsedInHtml(elements));
```

I'd like to refactor this function using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, and skip the need to define the variable `uniqClassSelectors`, but haven't been able to make it work.

Here is my refactored function that does not work (returns `accumulator is undefined`). I often get tripped up with `reduce()` in this regard. Why is `accumulator` undefined? Am I not using `forEach()` correctly inside the `reduce()` function? Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

```
let classesUsedInHtml = htmlCollection => {
  return Array.from(htmlCollection)
    .filter(element => element.classList.length > 0)
    .reduce((accumulator, element) => {
      return element.classList.forEach(
        classSelector =>
          accumulator.includes(classSelector)
            ? accumulator
            : accumulator.concat(classSelector)
      );
    }, []);
};
```

---

**EDIT**: removed the uneccessary `map()` from the function in question due to  Nina Scholz comment

Comment: why map if you do not take the return value (in the first code)? the second does not return what you want with `forEach`. it returns only undefined.

Comment: Good catch @NinaScholz. I will update the problem function above. But that won't solve the underlying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use another inner accumulator for the final `domTokenList` and take the outer `accumulator` as start value for the inner accumulator `acc2`.

```
let classesUsedInHtml = htmlCollection =>
    Array
        .from(htmlCollection)
        .filter(element => element.classList.length)
        .map(element => element.classList)
        .reduce((accumulator, domTokenList) =>
            domTokenList.reduce((acc2, classSelector) =>
                acc2.concat(acc2.includes(classSelector) ? [] : classSelector),
                accumulator
            ),
            []
        );
```

An other solution could be the use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for collecting unique class selectors.

```
let classesUsedInHtml = htmlCollection =>
    [...Array
        .from(htmlCollection)
        .filter(element => element.classList.length)
        .map(element => element.classList)
        .reduce((acc1, domTokenList) =>
            domTokenList.reduce((acc2, classSelector) => acc2.add(classSelector), acc1),
            new Set)
    ];
```

Comment: `DOMTokenList` is not an array, but does have the `forEach()` method in its prototype. So your code works if you add `Array.from(domTokenList).reduce...`. That's a good idea to use another `reduce()` on an array. But do you have any insight how to make it work using the `forEach()`?

Comment: as i wrote in comments, `forEach` does not return something, to work with. in this case, you need an outer variable, which would you like to eliminate. so either take `map`, or reduce for getting a new value.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see your updated comments before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

A step by step guide of this solution. The comment (// ->) shows the result of this step, which is passed to the next step.

1. Convert the `htmlCollection` to an array using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

   ```
   [...htmlCollection] // -> [htmlElement, htmlElement, etc...]
   ```
2. [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element to an array of classes (spread again):

   ```
   [htmlElement, htmlElement, etc...].map(({ classList }) => [...classList])) // -> [[class, class, etc...], [class, class, etc...], etc...]
   ```
3. Flatten the sub arrays by spreading into [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

   ```
   [].concat(...[[class, class, etc...], [class, class, etc...]], etc...) // -> [class, class, class, etc...]
   ```
4. Convert the array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and spread back to an array, to get the unique class names:

   ```
   [...new Set([class, class, class, etc...])] // -> [class1, class2, class3, etc...]
   ```

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

const classesUsedInHtml = (htmlCollection) =>
    [...new Set( // get unique items and convert to array
      [].concat(... // concat all classes' arrays
        [...htmlCollection] // convert the collection to an array
        .map(({ classList }) => [...classList])) // get arrays of classes
      )
    ];
    
const result = classesUsedInHtml(elements);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="a c">
  <span class="a b"></span>
  <span class="b c"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! I know I'm not supposed to use comments for "thanks", but I did not know about `Set` before. Really elegant with the spread operator, just the kind of approach I was looking for.

Comment: Can anyone explain what's going on throughout this solution beyond the provided comments?

Comment: @BrianZ - I've add a step by step breakdown of the solution.

Comment: So helpful that your instructions started from the inside of the code and flowed out. I was reading from the outside in and getting lost. Thanks again!